# Windows 8 network connections take minutes to establish

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8

I've recently installed Windows 8 on my Dell XPS laptop. In the past couple weeks, the network connections have taken longer than usual to establish. Here's what I mean:

In the past, when I woke the computer from sleep (either at home, work, or school), it would take at most 5 seconds to get connected to a network. Recently it has been more along the lines of 1-2 minutes. Often with Wi-Fi it won't connect at all. It connects, but never gets an IP address from the DHCP server. I end up with 169.x.x.x addresses for wifi. Usually if I restart my computer, it will work once I'm back up.

With my wired connection, it also takes about 10x longer than it should to connect. Instead of 3 seconds to link up, I end up waiting 30 seconds or more. The wired connection seems to work most of the time, though.

I thought the Wi-Fi might be a driver issue, but I just installed the newest driver for my wireless card I could find, to no avail. Any ideas what could be causing my networking woes?

UPDATE: As is nearly always the case for me, as soon as I ask the question, I find a solution. Or at least sort of. I had Internet Connection Sharing on for my Hyper-V VMs virtual switch. Once I turned that off, it connected right up. Then I turned it back on, and all appears to be working. If someone can explain how to prevent that, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had Internet Connection Sharing turned on for my Wi-Fi connection so my Hyper-V VMs could connect. As soon as I turned that off, my wireless connection worked. I turned it on again and all appears to be working.